# Pipeline plugin error on supereasy Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running this simple pipeline:

```
node ('main') {
   echo 'Hello World'
}
```

And I'm having the following error on job:

```
Started by user Paco
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/workspace/tespipeline
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
an exception which occurred:
    in field java.util.HashMap.loadFactor
    in object java.util.HashMap@660dfa72
    in field org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.closures
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@5f085500
    in object org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup@5f085500
Caused: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller can not access a member of class java.util.HashMap with modifiers "final"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:296)
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:288)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getFloat(Field.java:645)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1028)
Caused: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Unexpected illegal access exception
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1037)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(RiverObjectOutputStream.java:165)
    at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1360)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor55.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.JDKSpecific$SerMethods.callWriteObject(JDKSpecific.java:156)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.reflect.SerializableClass.callWriteObject(SerializableClass.java:191)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:976)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteFields(RiverMarshaller.java:1032)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteSerializableObject(RiverMarshaller.java:988)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.river.RiverMarshaller.doWriteObject(RiverMarshaller.java:854)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractObjectOutput.writeObject(AbstractObjectOutput.java:58)
    at org.jboss.marshalling.AbstractMarshaller.writeObject(AbstractMarshaller.java:111)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.lambda$writeObject$0(RiverWriter.java:144)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:136)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.pickles.serialization.RiverWriter.writeObject(RiverWriter.java:143)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:482)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgram(CpsThreadGroup.java:458)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.saveProgramIfPossible(CpsThreadGroup.java:445)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:372)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

My actual Jenkins version is 2.164.1 (the newer one), the pipeline version that I have installed is 2.6, but I also tried a previous one.

I also tried with google without luck.

Any idea about the problem?

Comment: Does declarative work or is it erroring similar to your scripted?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have another instance with an old backup and it works. Looks like something related a new version of Pipeline plugin or Jenkins. I'll try to find the problem upgrading step by step the plugins and also Jenkins version.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have declared a `pipeline`, then you can use `stages`, `stage` and `steps`, finally, run your `pipeline`.

I give you the following test code below.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo 'Building..'
            }
        }
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                echo 'Testing..'
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                echo 'Deploying....'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you need to use node, you can use the following [examples](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/)

I hope it may help you!

Comment: The script in the question aims to be a scripted pipeline as it looks.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is not a valid scripted pipeline syntax. [See documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55385001/pipeline-plugin-error-on-supereasy-jenkins-pipeline)

A `node` should contain a `stage`, then the `steps`

```
node('main'){
    stage('Print message'){
        echo 'Hello world!'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, using this code fails as well. It looks something related plugin version or maybe Jenkins new version

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, it was a problem with user permission in SO level. I've created a new instance and added a backup to it without changing the permission of the jenkins executor user, and it is working like a charm.

Thank you all, for your responses!

Comment: What does SO mean? Often on this site it stands for the name of this site, StackOverflow. But probably not in this case. I'm having similar error and searching for a fix. Jenkins job fails and the call stack includes similar entries.  But the exception in my case is actually stack overflow.